# ASPNETDB gets detached everytime the service is restarted

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express

I have an ASPNETDB.mdf file that I have attached to database from within SQL Server Management Studio. I use that database for Membership. When I have just attached the the mdf file and created a database everything works fine. Authentication works fine.But if I restart the computer or SQLExpress service itself ASPNETDB stops working. When I enter Management Studio I can ASPNETDB there, but has no plus sign to its left. And if I try to grant permission to a user through User mapping a dialog appears saying "one or more database are inaccessible and will not be displayed". How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Did you use deprecated features in your connection string, like `User Instance` and `AttachDbFileName`?

Comment: No, my connection string is data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ASPNETDB;User ID=clerk; Password=dsmf1914;

Comment: What does `SELECT user_access_desc, state_desc, is_auto_close_on, is_cleanly_shutdown FROM sys.databases` say for that database?

Comment: MULTI_USER ONLINE 0 0
MULTI_USER ONLINE 0 0
MULTI_USER ONLINE 0 0
MULTI_USER ONLINE 0 0
MULTI_USER ONLINE 1 0
MULTI_USER ONLINE 1 1
MULTI_USER ONLINE 0 0